# noUISlider con Jquery no asigna como parametro "audio.currentTime"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, bootstrap

La creación en el HTML del slider es ésta, hago uso de una framework, el nouislider. El Slider es porque estoy creando un reproductor con HTML y jQuery junto con Bootstrap. El slider tendría como funcionar, lógicamente, avanzar según vaya reproduciéndose el audio.

```
<div id="slider" class="slider shor slider-success"> </div>
```

En el JS tengo esto:

```
var slider = document.getElementById('slider'); 
audio = document.getElementById('audio1');
  $('#play1').click(function () {
   if ($("#audio1").get(0).paused) {
       $("#audio1").get(0).play();
       document.getElementById('tempo_atual').innerHTML = secToStr( audio1.currentTime);
       document.getElementById('tempo_total').innerHTML = secToStr( audio1.duration );
   } else {
       $("#audio1").get(0).pause();
  }
});
audio.addEventListener('timeupdate', atualizar , false);

noUiSlider.create(slider, {
    start: 0,
    range: {
        'min': 0,
        'max': audio.duration
    }
});
//slider1Value = document.getElementById('slider1-span'),
slider.noUiSlider.on('update', function( values, handle ){
    //slider1Value.innerHTML = values[handle];
  position = values[handle];
  audio.currentTime = position;
});

function atualizar(){
  document.getElementById('tempo_atual').innerHTML = secToStr( audio.currentTime);
  document.getElementById('tempo_total').innerHTML = secToStr( audio.duration);
}
```

Lo que se me ocurre es que en la función `actualizar()` vaya algo como esto:

```
slider.noUiSlider.set(audio.currentTime);
```

PERO NO ME FUNCIONA. ¿Lo hago en un lugar incorrecto? ¿Utilizo mal el `.set()`?
¿Cómo puedo solucionar este problema?

Alvaro Montoro:
Gracias por las correcciones, sucede es mi primera vez haciendo uso de Stack Overflow, además de haber escrito todo con prisa.

Comment: Hola @YelloWhale, bienvenido a StackOverflow. No hace falta que añadas un agradecimiento en la publicación. Una pregunta: cuando dices que no funciona, ¿cómo no funciona? ¿El slider no avanza lo suficiente? ¿Avanza demasiado? ¿Qué es lo que falla exactamente?

Comment: Siento que hacía falta, porque por más que leí un poco, no entendí cómo poner el código como lo que es, código.

Comment: En fin.
No hace nada. Por ejemplo, si pongo .set(10); En el navegador me pone el slider en la posición 10, pero el audio no avanza, está estancado.
Debería haber una forma de que ese valor se actualice, pero a diferencia de donde pongo el tiempo que ha transcurrido, el slider no funciona como quisiera.

Comment: El problema es que el slider se genera cuando aún no se ha cargado el audio, entonces no tienes `audio.duration` y falla la definición. Añadí una respuesta que soluciona el problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema está en el momento en el que creas el slider:

```
noUiSlider.create(slider, {
  start: 0,
  range: {
    'min': 0,
    'max': audio.duration
  }
});
```

Porque en ese momento, aún no se ha terminado de cargar el audio, no tienes `audio.duration` y no se sabe cuánto tiempo dura (si miras la consola de errores verás que hay un fallo que dice algo sobre el range no tiene un valor numérico).

La solución es simple: no inicialices el slider hasta que no se termine de cargar el audio. Para ello pon el código que inicializa el slider en una función que se llama cuando se lanza el evento `onloadeddata` del audio:

```
audio.onloadeddata = function() {
  // definición del slider y sus eventos aquí
}
```

Aparte de eso, para que el slider avance con el sonido, debes añadir el código que indicas en la función `atualizar()`. Pero ojo, entonces aparece otro problema al sonar el audio: cuando cambias el valor del slider se actualiza el `currentTime` del audio (en `slider.noUiSlider.on('update'...`), y cuando se actualiza el `currentTime` del audio se cambia el valor del slider (en `atualizar()`), lo que nos lleva a un bucle de actualizaciones y cambios de valor que hace que el sonido se escuche mal (o no se escuche directamente).

Una posible solución es usar una variable centinela y hacer que el valor del slider sólo afecte al valor de `currentTime` si el audio no está sonando. De este modo no se afectan entre sí y ya se escucha bien.

---

Aquí dejo un ejemplo cambiando lo mínimo tu código (y añadiendo HTML que faltaba):

```js
function secToStr(val) {
  return val;
}

function atualizar(){
  document.getElementById('tempo_atual').innerHTML = secToStr( audio.currentTime);
  document.getElementById('tempo_total').innerHTML = secToStr( audio.duration);
  slider.noUiSlider.set(audio.currentTime);
}


var slider = document.getElementById('slider'); 
audio = document.getElementById('audio1');
$('#play1').click(function () {
  if ($("#audio1").get(0).paused) {
    $("#audio1").get(0).play();
    document.getElementById('tempo_atual').innerHTML = secToStr( audio1.currentTime);
    document.getElementById('tempo_total').innerHTML = secToStr( audio1.duration );
  } else {
    $("#audio1").get(0).pause();
  }
});

audio.addEventListener('timeupdate', atualizar , false);

// espera a que se cargue el audio para inicializar el slider
audio.onloadeddata = function() {
  noUiSlider.create(slider, {
    start: 0,
    range: {
      'min': 0,
      'max': audio.duration
    }
  });

  //slider1Value = document.getElementById('slider1-span'),
  slider.noUiSlider.on('update', function( values, handle ){
    // para que el slider avance con el audio
    if (audio.paused) {
      //slider1Value.innerHTML = values[handle];
      position = values[handle];
      audio.currentTime = position;
    }
  });

}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/noUiSlider/8.3.0/nouislider.min.css"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/noUiSlider/8.3.0/nouislider.js"></script>

<div id="play1">Play/Pause Audio</div>
<div id="tempo_atual">0</div>
<div id="tempo_total">0</div>

<audio id="audio1">
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

<div id="slider" class="slider shor slider-success"> </div>
```

Comment: Wow, que impresionante, se corregía de manera muy simple.

Comment: Lamentablemente, tengo un error:
        audio.onloadeddata = function(){
  noUiSlider.create(slider, {
   start: 0,
   range: {
    'min': 0,
    'max': audio.duration
   }
  });

"audio" me sale en naranja, y no en rojo (uso Atom). Lo que quiere decir que, ese audio no es mi objeto jQuery.

Comment: audio no es jQuery en ningún momento del código. No comprendo que son los colores que indicas

Comment: O pudiera ser que no sea  eso en realidad. 
El Slider ya no sale en mi HTML.

Comment: Si, disculpa, audio no era objeto jQuery. Me refiero a esto –
<
audio = document.getElementById('audio1');
>
No es jQuery, ¡lo sé!

Comment: Prueba a ponerlo como el evento `timeupdate`, en una función aparte y añadiendo el evento con `addEventListener`. Es raro. ¿El snippet de arriba se ejecuta bien?

Comment: Error de llaves. Ya todo perfecto.
¡Muchas gracias por tu amable ayuda!

Comment: Si la respuesta de @AlvaroMontoro te ayudo a resolver tu problema, marca su respuesta como aceptada.